Running Solana RPC Nodes in Restricted Repair Only Mode
I am currently running an RPC node with --restricted-repair-only-mode to limit bandwidth in the following command:
exec solana-validator \
    --restricted-repair-only-mode \
    --no-os-network-limits-test \
    --gossip-host 39.183.161.82 \
    --gossip-port 8001 \
    --identity ./validator-keypair.json \
    --known-validator 7Np41oeYqPefeNQEHSv1UDhYrehxin3NStELsSKCT4K2 \
    --known-validator GdnSyH3YtwcxFvQrVVJMm1JhTS4QVX7MFsX56uJLUfiZ \
    --known-validator DE1bawNcRJB9rVm3buyMVfr8mBEoyyu73NBovf2oXJsJ \
    --known-validator CakcnaRDHka2gXyfbEd2d3xsvkJkqsLw2akB3zsN1D2S \
    --full-rpc-api \
    --no-voting \
    --ledger ./ledger \
    --accounts ./accounts \
    --snapshots ./snapshots \
    --log ./solana-rpc.log \
    --rpc-bind-address 0.0.0.0 \
    --rpc-port 8899 \
    --private-rpc \
    --dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 \
    --entrypoint 34.83.231.102:8001 \
    --entrypoint 147.28.180.247:8001 \
    --entrypoint 145.40.64.255:8001 \
    --entrypoint 147.28.134.81:8001 \
    --entrypoint 147.28.198.87:8001 \
    --expected-genesis-hash 5eykt4UsFv8P8NJdTREpY1vzqKqZKvdpKuc147dw2N9d \
    --wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record \
    --limit-ledger-size \
    --incremental-snapshot-interval-slots 0 \
    --no-snapshot-fetch

However, it fails with the following log:
[2024-07-13T00:56:37.285521769Z ERROR solana_validator] Failed to start validator: "Invalid port: 0"
After reviewing the code, it seems that the --restricted-repair-only-mode is not handled sufficiently which caused the problem. Is this flag currently not usable? Or is there any method that can be used to limit the bandwidth of the solana RPC node?

This may be a bug -- could you submit an issue to the agave repo at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/issues ?
